# Benefit of having variable assignment on the return line

Tags: c#

As stated, I'm curious if there's any benefit of doing:

```
return someNumber = CalculateResults(parameter);
```

versus doing:

```
someNumber = CalculateResults(parameter);
return someNumber;
```

or doing:

```
return CalculateResults(parameter);
```

Is there any performance gained in using one over the other?

Comment: Easier to read for me, and it saves a line of code.

Comment: @Jacob how can this be used to debug? When you're on the line the variable isn't assigned yet, and when stepping to the next line, return takes you up in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Destrictor I think the next step is the method's closing `}`.

Comment: I have never used the first version, it seems odd to me

Comment: @Destrictor, you can set breakpoint on the return line and check the someNumber variable.

Comment: @Rawling Really? I could've sworn... &gt;.&lt;

Comment: @Jacob as I said, breaking on the return line means the code hasn't executed, you'll have the previous value of someNumber.

Comment: @Destrictor, i'm talking about the second case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While with active optimizations probably all the three would be the same, they produce slightly different results without.

The first and the second have to declare a variable in the scope and return it, while the last  doesn't. I've tried to compile the following program:

```
int Calculate()
{
    return 42;
}

int FirstCase()
{
    int x;
    return x = Calculate();
}

int SecondCase()
{
    var x = Calculate();
    return x;
}

int ThirdCase()
{
    return Calculate();
}
```

Output with LINQPad:

```
FirstCase:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  call        UserQuery.Calculate
IL_0007:  dup         
IL_0008:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0009:  stloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_000A:  br.s        IL_000C
IL_000C:  ldloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_000D:  ret         

SecondCase:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  call        UserQuery.Calculate
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0009:  stloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_000A:  br.s        IL_000C
IL_000C:  ldloc.1     // CS$1$0000
IL_000D:  ret         

ThirdCase:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  call        UserQuery.Calculate
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // CS$1$0000
IL_0008:  br.s        IL_000A
IL_000A:  ldloc.0     // CS$1$0000
IL_000B:  ret
```

The third case is a little shorter. I also prefer that approach, because it feels more fluent than allocating a variable for it. The only reason I'd use a variable is to try to "document" what the method does by giving a meaningful name to the return value, through the variable.

Comment: This assumes that `someNumber` is a local, as opposed to say a field or property.

Comment: @Servy True. But from the author's question I think that he's aware that there's a difference between setting a local variable and a field, while his question was only related to the performance. Good point, either way.

Comment: Well, from a performance point of view, one is setting a field, and another is going to be optimized away.  Since we don't know which he's using, we don't know which is the case, and thus can't give an answer.

Comment: @Servy We know, though, that this is the best case. In case of a field or a property, the method will have to access the instance passed to it and write the value on the given field. Needless to say, it's longer in terms of IL for the first two methods -- But I'd rather avoid making my answer too long with additional IL blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical benefit between the first two, but the second one is more readable than the first in my opinion.

```
return CalculateResults(parameter);
```

is even better if `someNumber` doesn't persist in any way, you should be careful of that.

and takes one less instruction(although i wouldn't be surprised if the optimizer did that for you already)

Comment: If `someNumber` is a field, not a local, then no, it's not the same to just remove it.

Comment: thus the wording: "if `someNumber` doesn't persist in any way,"

Answer (score 1):

Having on separate lines will help with debugging like Jacob stated. If you do not need to store/manipulate the data being returned then you should go ahead and return without allocating a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this

```
return someNumber = CalculateResults(parameter);
```

when possible. Saves a line and helps when you're debugging. You can simply hover over someNumber to get what the return value is.

Performance gain if any will be negligible from not doing an assignment operation. (Compiler will probably optimize it anyway.)